# $\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N} } \bigcap_{j \in \mathbb{N} } {C_i}_j = \bigcap_{j \in \mathbb{N} } \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N} } {C_i}_j$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

Is it true that the countable union of the countable intersection is equal to the countable intersection of the countable union of any set?

$$\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N} } \bigcap_{j \in \mathbb{N} } {C_i}_j = \bigcap_{j \in \mathbb{N} } \bigcup_{i \in  \mathbb{N} } {C_i}_j $$

Comment: No, but there is a formula for that: [Complete distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_distributive_lattice).

Comment: It doesn't even hold for finite case: $$(\{1\}\cap\{2\})\cup(\{1\}\cap\{2\})=\varnothing\neq\{1,2\}=(\{1\}\cup\{2\})\cap(\{1\}\cup\{2\})$$